# Xamarin android how to override onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm developing an Android app with Xamarin and mvvmcross. For Android 6.0 I succeeded to ask runtime permissions, it is working well, but I do not have access to my MainActivity code so I don't know how to override the onRequestPermissionsResult callback, does anyone has a clue on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Alexander I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I also wonder if either of you found an answer. I am using `Plugin.Permissions` but not Xamarin Forms. Just "native" Android in Xamarin. Did you find an Activity to override with the method you're asking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current `Activity` using the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`

James Montemagno has wrapped the API calls into one of his `Xamarin.Plugins`:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/CurrentActivity

In your `Application` subclass (MainApplication) you do some minor setup and then you have access to the `Activity` via the `CrossCurrentActivity.Current` property.

```
public override void OnCreate() { base.OnCreate();
   RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this); 
}

public override void OnTerminate() { 
  base.OnTerminate(); 
  UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this); 
} 

public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity; 
} 

public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity) { 
   CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity; 
}
```

- See more at: http://motzcod.es/post/133609925342/access-the-current-android-activity-from-anywhere
- Available on NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity * Install into your Xamarin.Android Client project.

Google Docs: [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Permissions Plugin for Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions) to ask for permissions at runtime and get result.

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);

if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    //Permission was granted.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [@Evk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39473995/2456536):

Most likely you use wrong `Permission` type (there are several types named `Permission` in different namespaces). Try this:

```
class Aplication : Android.App.Activity,
    Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        string[] permissions,
        Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults
    ) {
    }
}
```