# Xamarin – Cannot override OnRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, runtime-permissions

I've got a class that extends `Activity` and implements `IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.

I want to use `OnRequestPermissionResult` and I coded it exactly as in [XamarinBlog](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) (section Handle Permission Request) and [Monodroid Github](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android-m/RuntimePermissions/MainActivity.cs#L218) but I always get **`no suitable method to override`** error.

```cs
namespace App1
{
    class Aplication : Android.App.Activity,
                       Android.Support.V4.AppActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
    {

        public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode,
            string[] permissions,
            Permission[] grantResults
        ) { }

    }
}
```

How can I use the new Marshmallow permissions in Xamarin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely you use wrong `Permission` type (there are several types named `Permission` in different namespaces). Try this:

```
class Aplication : Android.App.Activity,
    Android.Support.V4.AppActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        string[] permissions,
        Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults
    ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a hero!!